# Sending tcp packets in PHP limit

Tags: tcp, max, fwrite

im trying to send a large packet ( 9170 bytes ) using fwrite to a tcp server

```
            fwrite($this->_socket, $data);
```

Problem is it send 8192 first then send the left 978 bytes
and i want to decrease the amount sent from 8192 to 1444 for each time it is sent

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Server does not accept more than 1444 bytes at a time

Comment: The client doesn't have to arrange its transmissions to meet the server's reception requirements. The TCP layer will do that. The client can send 9,840 bytes and if the server only accepts 1444 bytes at a time, it will still get all of them.

Answer (score 1):

The TCP layer will do this, you don't have to. If you write 9,880 bytes and the server only tries to read 1,444 of them, it will get up to the first 1,444 bytes. The next time the server tries to read, it will get the next byte or bytes.

The client doesn't have to arrange its transmissions to meet the reception requirements of the server. The TCP layer's flow control will handle this automatically.

You're solving a non-problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to [fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) documentation the optional third parameter of fwrite is length. It denontes maximum number of bytes that will be sent before end of string is reached. Won't this be the solution to your problem?

See the examples in comments below the documentation, they contain examples how to use fwrite with length.

Comment: unfortunately it stops after *length* and does not split it

Comment: Just execute the fwrite in a loop, sending next portion of data in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

$data is a string right ? You can split using substr() and then just keep sending.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, just send 1444 bytes and wait for a user-level acknowledgement message from the the server.  That will give the appearance of sending 1444 bytes at a time.  It will also be painfully slow.

The root problem is that TCP is not capable of sending messages any longer than one byte - it streams bytes.

Add a protocol on top of TCP that can send messages.